# Duplicate values when joining across three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm having some issued where multiple duplicate values are appearing in my output when trying to join three tables together. My data is structured as below :

**T1 (Transactions_Table)**

```
Trans_ID    Acc_No    Trans_Code    Trans_Amt 
6243        11111111  0690          35.0  
4534        11111111  0876          10.0 
5987        22222222  0690          -10.0
```

**T2 (Translation_Table)**

```
Acc_No    Prod_Code
11111111  45
22222222  65
```

**T3 (Product_Table)**

```
Prod_Code    Prod_Desc
45           Current Account
65           Credit Card
```

The translation table (T2) allows for transactions (T1) to be joined through to find what kind of product the account is (T3).

- In T1, the Trans_ID is always unique however the Acc_No will appear
  multiple times, as will Trans_Code
- In T2, the Acc_No is unique however the Prod_Code will appear multiple times
- In T3, Prod_Code is unique

My current attempt is shown below. The query is trying to take all transactions (T1) and calculate the sum and count of all transactions across the different types (Trans_Type), grouped by product. The CASE WHEN is to split the positive and negative values.

```
SELECT T1.TRANS_CODE,
       T3.PROD_DESC,
       SUM  (CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT < 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_NEGATIVE,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT < 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT END) AS COUNT_NEGATIVE,
       SUM  (CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT > 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_POSTIIVE,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT > 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT END) AS COUNT_POSITIVE
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.ACC_NO = T2.ACC_NO
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T2.PROD_CODE = T3.PROD_CODE
GROUP BY T1.TRANS_CODE,
         T3.PROD_DESC
```

Expected output here would be :

```
Trans_Type    Prod_Desc        Sum_Positive    Count_Positive    Sum_Negative    Count_Negative
0690          Current Account  35.0            1                 -               -     
0690          Credit Card      -               -                 -10.0           1 
0876          Current Account  10.0            1                 -               -
```

However my sums & counts are coming out way in excess of what I know to be true.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Updated Code**

```
SELECT T1.TRANS_CDE,
  T3.PROD_DESC,
SUM  (CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT < 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_NEGATIVE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT < 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT END) AS COUNT_NEGATIVE,
SUM  (CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT > 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_POSTIIVE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT > 0 THEN T1.TRANS_AMT END) AS COUNT_POSITIVE
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T2.ACC_NO, 
        MIN(PROD_CODE) AS PROD_CODE 
        FROM T2 
        GROUP BY ACC_NO) T2
ON T1.ACC_NO = T2.ACC_NO
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T2.PROD_CODE = T3.PROD_CODE
GROUP BY T1.TRAN_CDE,
  T3.PROD_DESC
```

Comment: Please set up a db fiddle of some sort to illustrate your problem.  Your query looks fine based on the description of the data.

Comment: Please post what you are currently getting from this query?

Comment: For your sample data, your query works fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b5917/3

Comment: Are the derived columns named correctly? `...WHEN T1.TRANS_AMT < 0...` is named SUM_POSITIVE!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Your query looks fine based on the description of your tables.  If your numbers are too high, I am guessing that the one of your tables has unexpected duplicates.

Do either of these return any rows?

```
select ac_no
from t2
group by ac_no
having count(*) >= 2;

select prod_code
from t3
group by prod_code
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If these queries do not return any rows, then the query would seem to be returning the correct values.

EDIT:

Here are two ways to select only one row from `T2`.  The changes are needed only in the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT T2.ACC_NO, MIN(t2.PROD_CODE) as PROD_CODE
      FROM T2
      GROUP BY T2.ACC_NO
     ) T2
     ON T1.ACC_NO = T2.ACC_NO LEFT JOIN
     T3
     ON T2.PROD_CODE = T3.PROD_CODE
```

Or:

```
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT T2.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.ACC_NO ORDER BY T2.ACC_NO) as seqnum
      FROM T2
      GROUP BY T2.ACC_NO
     ) T2
     ON T1.ACC_NO = T2.ACC_NO AND
        T2.seqnum = 1 LEFT JOIN
     T3
     ON T2.PROD_CODE = T3.PROD_CODE
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, you seem to have cracked it. My relationship table (T2) has worrying duplicates I wasn't aware of. Is it possible to use Distinct, or maybe MAX, to only select one record from this table? It's not important which record is chosen.

Comment: Gordon, perhaps being a bit dim here but I am recieving a 'missing keyword' error each time. Have updated my original post with revised PL SQL code.

Comment: @ScottCee . . . I don't see an obvious problem in your code.